# Code executed using load()() cannot access functions from its caller

Tags: lua, opencomputers

So I am writing and testing my new OS kernel and just finished the part where it loads up /bin/init.lua, I tested it, it loads up init.lua, andddd it exit mid-execution. I have a function in init.lua where it prints out test message, but it need to access two specific function from the kernel but it cannot seem to access it. Any idea how to make a code executed by load()() be able to access functions from its caller?

Just in case you need to see the source code: https://github.com/WattanaGaming/OCLinux/blob/master/boot/kernel/OCLinux.lua#L86

Comment: Is `gpuInvoke` equals to `nil` inside `init.lua` ?

Comment: No, but init.lua seemingly exit mid-execution from nothing.

Comment: You can pass your functions as arguments: `load(initCode)(func1, func2)` and receive them in `init.lua` in the first line `local func1, func2 = ...; _INITVER = "1.0"`

Comment: When you `load` a new chunk, it usually doesn't have any upvalues except for its environment, so you can't access any locals from the surrounding code.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff your code does not work

Comment: What is the output of `print(pcall(assert(load(initCode))))` ?

Comment: attempt to index global 'fs' (a nil value)

Comment: So, you have global FUNCTION `fs` in you main program and accessing non-existing global TABLE `fs` in `init.lua`.  It looks like something is wrong here.